# My youtube embed code doesn't work on html website

Tags: html

```
   <center>
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/BrI7VRfqgo4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I know its been posted around, but nothing's been working for me at the moment. I have HTML website and trying to put the html video youtube embed code, but its not working for me.
My site is online, very simple html.. And it has http in the video embed code as well..
I tried a lot, but cant get it working in any way.

Regards

Comment: Do you see any console errors in the browser ?

Comment: Nope, it shows its clean.. doesn't show anything in console..

Comment: What happens if you try from a different browser?  Which browser are you trying this from?  Some handle <iframes> differently and plugins like NoScript could be blocking you. You also want to verify that your <iframe> is running from a code block that is accessible by the browser (for example not inside a <noscript> tag) and that the browser is capable of running scripts, etc.

Comment: Well, it shows now, `Page Not Found`.. at least it shows the iframe now

Comment: I have tried IE, Firefox and chrome.. same problem.

Comment: is it a turkish airlines video?

Comment: Yes, it was turkish airline, now I changed it to university video, embedding is enabled on that one too.

Comment: i searched for it on youtube is says it's a turkish airlines video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable embedding first before the `embed` code will work from other websites.

- Log in to https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U
- Click `Edit` on the video you want to embed
- Click on `Advanced Settings` in the tab below
- Click `Allow Embedding` to enable it under the `Distribution options` section.
- Click `Save Changes` to save the new configuration.
- Now your embed link is ready to be embedded on other websites!

Comment: Hi,  I have tried embedding different videos that are embedded on other websites, but none is working on my html page.

Comment: The other videos that you have tried to embed have already enabled embedding which makes it possible.  Double check that `Allow Embedding` is enabled in the `Advanced Settings` section of your video.

Comment: Updated my answer to find the section easily

Comment: Hi, My all videos are always have embedding on,  I always check that.. problem is that its not showing up on my html..

my page is [link](http://ultimatestudents.com/partners.html)

try if it works for you

Comment: Yes it loads 1 YouTube video for me just fine in Chrome. So it's probably an issue with the browser you are trying to load it from.

Comment: Are you trying to access YouTube from inside that same network?  Since it's a school's network it's likely that they are blocking YouTube requests at the gateway which is why you can't access it from inside the network but you can from outside (like I just verified).

Comment: For me it shows, `Page Not Found` iframe now in chrome.. can you please try again the link once more if its loading for you..   I made some changes, let me know if its still working.  Sorry for bothering again :(

Comment: Yes it loads a London School Of Commerce Introductory video just fine.

Comment: Nope, I am opening it from my home network.. The site is hosted on ipage.

Comment: okay, thank you so much..  Let me see why it isn't loading for me..    I really really appreciate your kind help..

Answer (score 0):

```
<p align="left">
  <object height="385" width="640">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/LsEU_93SC4c&rel=0?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" height="385" width="640">
  </object>
</p>
```

Change the third line to your video number/name.

Answer (score 0):

I don'tknow it it can be of any help. 
I needed just the audio, so I changed height to "0" and width to"0" and it works on IE and Firefox. 
It doesn't work with Chrome and Opera.
Here the simple link. 
Just insert it as it is. I inserted it at the bottom of the page before

or go to my age and see if how it works:
https://www.carniaexpress.com/friuli-per-gruppi/raduno-alpini-triveneto-tolmezzo 
If you wish to see the video just change height and width...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: teh link is: <iframe width="0" height="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/477XZHDPbV8?&autoplay=1">
</body>